# LaTeX istgame draw game tree with continuum of branches and discrete moves

Tags: trees, technical-drawing, istgame

I want to draw the following game tree in LaTeX and hopefully `istgame` as that is what I am using for other drawings. I have no problems drawing the sectors using `istgame` such as the top two circles (I actually drew triangles which in LaTeX, but either is fine for me). However, for the final sector, where from a node, I have a continuum of branches plus one (or more) separate branch, I cannot get it to work. Here is the target tree [image: game tree to be drawn in question]
And here is the LaTeX I have tried

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{istgame}

\begin{document}
    \begin{istgame}
        
        \xtdistance{15mm}{25mm}
        \istroot(1){S}
        \istb{a_1}[r] \istbm
        \endist
        
        \xtdistance{15mm}{25mm}
        \istroot(3)(1-1){B}
        \istb{A}[al]{u_1}
        \endist
        \istrootcntm(4)(1-1){B}
        \istb{a_2}[r] \istbm
        \endist
    \end{istgame}
\end{document}
```

LaTeX output for now
[image: LaTeX output]

There is this [question on tex.se](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/653173/how-to-design-a-decision-node-with-both-descrete-and-continuum-action-set) with the following code, however it just sets a "random" (by trial and error) growth direction, can I do this automatically?

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{istgame}

\begin{document}
    \begin{istgame}
        \cntmdistance*{20mm}{20mm}
        \istroot(0)
        \istb*<grow=-135>{r}[above]
        \endist
        \cntmAistb{0}[left,near end]{1}[right,near end]
        \cntmApreset{.7}
        \istrootcntmA(0)
        \istbA*(1.5){}{a}
        \endist
    \end{istgame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! This is a good first question! Given the answer you linked is, I believe, by the package author, I suspect `istgame` doesn't support doing this automatically. That doesn't mean it can't be done automatically, but I'm not sure how it would be determined. Do you have an algorithm in mind for determining the growth direction?

Comment: @cfr I suppose if it cannot be automatically be done, I can go about by trial and error, as I'm only going to draw one or two of these. There is a macro that gives the height of the triangle and the tree height is set immediately before this part of the tree in code so I could probably calculate a growth direction in code using that.

Comment: The package author might have more ideas. You could try emailing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### tree structure:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}     
\usepackage{istgame}

\begin{document}    
\begin{istgame}[font=\scriptsize]    
\xtdistance{15mm}{60mm}
\istroot(0)[chance node]{N}
  \istb  \istb  \endist
\xtInfoset(0-1)(0-2)
\cntmdistance*{15mm}{25mm}
%% left part
\istrootcntm(1a)(0-1)
  \istb  \istbm  \endist
\istrootcntm(2a)(1a-1)
  \istb  \istbm  \endist
% additional branch
\xtdistance{15mm}{60mm}
\istroot(2aA)(2a)
  \istb  \istbm  \endist
% back to main
\cntmdistance*{15mm}{25mm}
\istroot(3a)(2a-1)
  \istb  \istb  \endist    
%% right part
\istrootcntm(1b)(0-2)
  \istb  \istbm  \endist
\istroot(2b)(1b-1)
  \istb  \istb  \endist    
\end{istgame}
\end{document}
```

### full code:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone} 

\usepackage{istgame}

\begin{document}

\begin{istgame}[font=\scriptsize]

\xtdistance{15mm}{60mm}
\istroot(0)[chance node]{N}
  \istB{\mbox{negotiator}}[al]{p}[br]
  \istB{\mbox{non-negotiator}}[ar]{1-p}[bl]
  \endist

\xtInfoset(0-1)(0-2)

\cntmdistance*{15mm}{25mm}

%% left part
\cntmistb{s}[below left,at end]{\infty}[below right,at end]
\istrootcntm(1a)(0-1)
  \istb{a_1}[above right,at end] \istbm
  \endist
\cntmistb{0}[below left,at end]{\infty}[below right,at end]
\istrootcntm(2a)(1a-1)
  \istb{a_2}[above right,at end] \istbm
  \endist
% additional branch
\xtdistance{15mm}{60mm}
\istroot(2aA)(2a)
  \istb{A}[al]{(a_1-s,b-a_1)} \istbm
  \endist
% back to main
\cntmdistance*{15mm}{25mm}
\istroot(3a)(2a-1)
  \istb{A}[al]{(a_2-s,b-a_1d(a_1-a_2))}
  \istb{D}[ar]{(0,0)}
  \endist    

%% right part
\cntmistb{0}[below left,at end]{\infty}[below right,at end]
\istrootcntm(1b)(0-2)
  \istb{a_1}[above right,at end] \istbm
  \endist
\istroot(2b)(1b-1)
  \istb{A}[al]{(a_1-s,b-a_1)}
  \istb{B}[ar]{(0,0)}
  \endist

%% more text
\xtTimeLineH[draw=none](1b){0}{6}{S}
\xtTimeLineH[draw=none](2b){0}{6}{B}
\xtTimeLineH[draw=none](3a){0}{6}{S}
\end{istgame}
  
\end{document}
```

Comment: I hoped you'd answer this!

Comment: @cfr Actually your comment above led to this answer.